# Converting date and time data

Tags: r, datetime

I have date data formatted in an odd way that I would like to clean up in R.

The dates are in format `"d-Mon-y hh:mm:sec AM"`. For example `"1-Feb-05 12:00:00 AM"`. The day and time are useless to me, however I would like to be able to use the month and year while also converting them to date-time format.

I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `zoo::as.yearmon(as.Date("1-Feb-05 12:00:00 AM", "%d-%b-%y"))`? or

`format(as.Date("1-Feb-05 12:00:00 AM", "%d-%b-%y"), '%Y %b')`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with handy `lubridate` parsers and extractors. First convert the string into a datetime and then extract the month and the year:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
tibble(datetime = "1-Feb-05 12:00:00 AM") %>%
  mutate(
    datetime = dmy_hms(datetime),
    year = year(datetime),
    month = month(datetime)
    )
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   datetime             year month
#>   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2005-02-01 00:00:00  2005     2
```

Created on 2018-05-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).